# Why go template not rendered?

Tags: go

I'm very new to Go and try to render an html form template `interface.html` which is on the same directory as my hello.go.

The relevant function in `hello.go` is:

```
func UserCreateForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var err error
    t := template.New("interface")        // Create a template.
    t, err = t.ParseFiles("interface.html") // Parse template file.
    log.Println(t)
    t.Execute(w, t)
    log.Println("template rendered")
    log.Println(err)

}
```

When I `GET` the url, the `template rendered` is logged on terminal but no template is being rendered.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I add `log.Println(t)` . It prints out `&{<nil> 0xc8200fa0c0 <nil> 0xc8201060a0}` while the html file is clearly there and not empty.
Also `log.Println(err)` returns `<nil>`

Comment: Stop ignoring the returned errors so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: I'd start by not ignoring the error values that might be returned by both `t.ParseFiles` and `t.Execute`

Comment: As mentioned by the other two, if your code isn't working as expected a good starting point would be to check the errors returned. Maybe `ParseFiles` fails? Additionally, you should print some information about what value `t` holds. Does it actually have anything to print? Maybe the file it read had no data in it and you just have an empty string now.

Comment: guys, strangely enough, when I added an `err` instead of `_` to  `ParseFiles` assignment, I get `undefined: err`. So please be specific on how to do so.

Comment: That's because you're using `t, _ =` meaning everything on the left hand side has already been declared, which is not the case with err. So you need `var err error` above those two lines or `:=` with a variable other than `t` for the first return value (`t2, err :=`).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal The template file is not empty. It has some basic html but don't know why is rendered as `&{<nil> 0xc820010e00 <nil> 0xc82000bcc0}`

Comment: Yeah I asked that question not because I thought your template file was actually empty but to get you thinking about the places where failures could occur. Inspect that template a bit further. Perhaps there is a syntax error which is causing the parse to fail. Was err nil?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realised what caused the problem:
When I define the New template, the name in `""` should be same as the one `ParseFiles` line.

So one correct whay to do it:

```
func UserCreateForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var err error
    t := template.New("interface.html")     // notice .html is added
    t, err = t.ParseFiles("interface.html") // Parse template file.
    log.Println(t)
    t.Execute(w, t)
    log.Println("rendering template")
    log.Println(err)
    }
```

More elegantly, one can get the template in one line, like:

```
func UserCreateForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("interface.html") // Parse template file.
    log.Println(t)
    t.Execute(w, t)
    log.Println("rendering template")
    log.Println(err)

}
```